# How are the currents induced by the E-field and H-field flows on a sphere?

Tags: rf, electromagnetic, wave, near-field

[image]

Please correct me if I am wrong?
We consider a sphere made of thin metal, with a radius of 1 m, at 20 km distance from an AM transmitter operating at 1 MHz. The alternating current in the transmitter tower (left in the picture) flows vertically

1. How are the currents induced by the E-field, flowing on the sphere?
   As the AC in the tower flows vertically, I think also on the sphere the current flows vertically. see picture [image]
2. How are the currents induced by the H-field, flowing on the sphere?
   using the right-hand rule, the magnetic field will flow parallel to the equator of the sphere

Comment: I think this should be an edit to your previous question, instead of a new one :)